# Autostart Kodi in 21.04 doesn't get focus

Tags: 21.04, autostart, kodi

For the past few years I've been autostarting Kodi by adding an application definition as '.config/autostart/kodi.desktop'.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=kodi
Hidden=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=kodi
Comment=kodi
```

Always worked great until my recent upgrade to 21.04 on all my media boxes. Now when Kodi autostarts, my OSMC remote (using USB dongle) doesn't work immediately. I can see a mouse pointer infront of Kodi which is new. If I click once using an external mouse then Kodi gains focus and I can use the OSMC remote.

There's nothing else of mine set to autostart and I've tried disabling the two Ubuntu default items too.

Subsequent loads of Kodi from the task bar have no issue as Kodi gains focus.

Has something been added in 21.04 that gains focus after autostarted applications? Is there a workaround for this?

Many thanks,

James

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a Wayland issue. Reverting to Xorg for now.

This isn't the ideal answer but seems to resolve the problem.

Edit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf:

```
[daemon]
# Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
WaylandEnable=false
```

Comment: yep, kodi does not support wayland. Wayland is default since Ubuntu 21.04